# How to publish local and remote ejb api using maven

Tags: maven, ejb

I have an ejb with stateless session bean. I have interfaces for each of the bean to be access or called remotely from another ejb from another machine. In invy, I remember we're using something like: publish-remote, publish-api. Can the same be done with maven?

Publish the interfaces in a separate jar, to be included in another project.

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have separate maven projects which is the usual way to separate interface (api) and the implementation. Than of course you can deploy the interface and implementation separately.

Comment: Yes, but what if I have the interface and implementation in 1 project. Is there a way to create an api jar for the interface?

Comment: Not really and the best is to "Refactor" the build in such case to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Maven is able to generate your client jar by itself, using maven-ejb-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/index.html

```xml
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- this is false by default -->
          <generateClient>true</generateClient>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```

Then, it will generate a client, and you'll be able to use it as a dependency:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejb-project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  [...]
</project>
```

or better

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejb-project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>ejb</type>
              <classifier>client</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  [...]
</project>
```

I don't have any true example (I'm on my personal computer, not my working computer), but I remember we used dependency with the second method.

Comment: Thanks, it does work! :-) But, can we exclude the class files? When I run my maven build, it also included the actual implementation. If possible I only wanted to package the interface. I tried using clientIncludes configuration but failed.

Comment: Exclusion patterns can be added.  See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html